# Making a Command Window Larger

Tags: c#, console-application

I was wondering if there was any way, setting or line of code wise, that would allow me to make a console window (like for a console application) larger or make it display more. For example, I recently finished a project where I ended up having to make the output split into columns because the console window only displayed the last 389 numbers (Yes I counted after I fixed it, all together I had 501 lines, one intro line and 500 numbers). I just figured someone on here may have an idea of how to fix it other than just using columns. P.S. I used `"\t"` to make the columns if anyone was wondering.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, [Console.SetWindowSize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setwindowsize%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

> Sets the height and width of the console window to the specified values.

Depending on the nature of your console app, you may also want to make a call to

[Console.SetBufferSize()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.setbuffersize(v=vs.110).aspx)

> Sets the height and width of the screen buffer area to the specified values.

to modify the size of the scrollback buffer.